# INDEX_SIZE_ERR when clicking a link with very basic jQuery in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hyperlink

Getting following error by clicking multiple times on a simple link with some basic jQuery attached to it in Chrome Version 20.0.1132.57:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 undefined
```

Here's a live demo of the very basic and simple code, to trigger the error, simply spam the link several times with your console log open (developer tools): http://jsfiddle.net/ZkXDy/

Comment: Same version of Chrome here, spam clicked the link with Console open... nothing.  Maybe it's an extension you have installed or something?

Comment: I used window.setInterval and had it click about 4k times.. No error like that popped up  http://jsfiddle.net/ZkXDy/1/

Comment: Thanks for heading me in the proper direction, tried deactivating and reactivating my extensions one by one and seems Google Dictionary (by Google) was causing the issue when the fast clicking became a double click and triggered the extension which led to some sort of bug!

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. Solved my issue too. Change to an answer and I'll +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posted the solution in comments but figured it would be more visible as an answer to anyone with the same issue.

Tried deactivating and reactivating my extensions one by one and seems **Google Dictionary (by Google)** was causing the issue when the fast clicking became a double click and triggered the extension which led to some sort of bug!

Thanks to MrOBrian for heading me in the proper direction