# Chrome exception

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I always get this exception in Chrome, that appears to be related to google dictionary extension. Is there a way to filter this from appearing all the time ? Or maybe this is just a fix for ?

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
    at J (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:14:142)
    at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:16:393)
    at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
    at miscellaneous_bindings:286:9
    at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:393:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:253:22)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638657/index-size-err-when-clicking-a-link-with-very-basic-jquery-in-chrome).

Comment: Well it's related to google dictionary extension. I trying to find out if there is a fix for or possibly just filter that out of the console.

Comment: Either filter, disable the extension or send a report to Google and see if they fix it :) Not sure if/how you can filter it though.

Comment: :) That sounds like a good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disabled the Google Dictionary Extension.

Comment: OMG.. I spent all day trying to find the reason. Working with AngularJS framework.